# Naming convention for class that holds multiple objects

Tags: design-patterns, naming-conventions

I have a big MVC project that I'm working on.

For a particular user logged in, I try to keep all the info about the user and some session data and other details in one container-type object. For any function that needs info about the user/session/etc I fetch it from this object. This saves me from calling the backend again and again.

Is there a naming convention for such objects? (There are helpers, managers, facades etc - is there a pattern for such objects)

PS - I know this is a one line answer, but help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It the goal is to reduce server round trips, I would call it a Cache: something like UserSessionCache.

[This codinghorror post](https://blog.codinghorror.com/i-shall-call-it-somethingmanager/) is a good guide to what to consider when naming a class.